# Data.frame filtering using %in%

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
  qualifiers symbols values
1        Buy    AAPL  326.0
2       Sell    MSFT  598.3
3       Sell   GOOGL  201.5
```

**I want to keep only the rows where `qualifiers` is "Sell", and then remove `qualifiers` column.**

So the new `data.frame` would be:

```
  symbols values
1    MSFT  598.3
2   GOOGL  201.5
```

---

Here is what I've tried:

```
# Select the rows with "Sell" qualifier
valid_symbols <- df$symbols[df$qualifiers == "Sell"]

# Keep only these
df <- df[df$symbols %in% valid_symbols]

# Remove qualifiers column
df$qualifiers <- NULL
```

Line 1 is working as expected:

```
> valid_symbols
[1] MSFT  GOOGL
Levels: AAPL GOOGL MSFT
```

But line 2 doesn't:

```
> df
  symbols values
1    AAPL  326.0
2    MSFT  598.3
3   GOOGL  201.5
```

It seems like it is filtering out by column instead of by line.

---

So I wonder:

1. What is wrong in my code
2. Is there a most efficient/elegant way to achieve what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the code is not working is because the `,` is needed.  By default, without using the `,`, it thinks that we are providing the column index/column names etc.

```
df <- df[df$symbols %in% valid_symbols,]
#OP's code
df$qualifiers <- NULL
```

If the non-numeric columns are `factor`, then we may need to wrap with `droplevels` to remove the unused levels in those columns

```
df <- droplevels(df)
```

---

However, this can be done with `subset`

```
subset(df, qualifiers == "Sell", select = -1)
```

Or with `dplyr` `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(qualifiers == "Sell") %>%
    select(2:3)
```